# Wired Firebase Error - [cloud_firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to debug an app from a distance. Everything I do locally where I am I tested on emulators, even real phones just like the client has all works perfectly well. I get data loaded from firebase without a problem. This app has been running for months without a problem on the client phone. Recently problems started coming up and I was trying to figure out where they emerged from. As I said, when I ran the app, all worked great even on real devices with the same Android version. This is just an Android app.

With debugging and not being able to have the faulty device near me, I found to that the error. `[cloud_firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff.`

Now the problem is that I have no clue why for me it would work perfectly. Here is the code snippet:

```
await firestoreInstance
          .collection("users/")
          .orderBy('number')
          .get(GetOptions(source: Source.server))
          .then((querySnapshot) {

        // Process data
       
        });
```

How can I dig deeper or find out what is faulty on the client side. All dependencies and stuff are up to date and work perfectly fine when I run the app.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: Interesting issue. Can you try https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/discussions/5708#discussioncomment-5162613?

Comment: I will try. One more update is that it works perfectly well when they connect to a hotspot but does not work on wifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was not due to the code. It was from the Client's WIFI. After he reseted it, it worked perfectly.